# SVG animation StopLight

Tags: html, animation, svg

I am creating a stoplight using SVG animation. I chose rectangles to use (i may switch to circles). I am having issues with the fill-opacity and the mouse effects.

**What I want-** I want the lights to be barely visible(dim) on initial load and when you hover over it with your mouse it turns bright and then when you take your mouse off it turns back to barely visible.

**What is Happening-** On initial load of html page all the lights are lit up. Once I hover over a light, nothing happens, when I take my mouse off a light it turns off. After I do that on all the lights and all the lights are off. It then works properly how I want it.

**My Code**

```
<svg width="500" height="800">
<!--Stoplight Pole-->
<line x1="100" y1="100" x2="400" y2="100" style="stroke: green; stroke-width:50" />
<line x1="400" y1="0" x2="400" y2="600" style="stroke: green; stroke-width:50" />
<rect x="300" y="600" height="100" width="200"></rect>

<!--Begin Stoplight-->
<rect id="stoplight" x="30" y="0" height="300" width="100" fill="black"></rect>

<rect id="redlight" x="55" y="25" height="60" width="50" fill="red" 
onmouseover="this.style.stroke = 'red'; evt.target.setAttribute('opacity','1.0'); this.style['stroke-width'] = 4; 
onmouseout="this.style.stroke = 'red'; evt.target.setAttribute('opacity', '0.5'); this.style['stroke-width'] = 1;"></rect>

<rect id="yellowlight" x="55" y="125" height="60" width="50" fill="yellow" 
onmouseover="this.style.stroke = 'yellow'; evt.target.setAttribute('opacity', '1.0'); this.style['stroke-width'] = 4;" 
onmouseout="this.style.stroke = 'yellow'; evt.target.setAttribute('opacity','0.5'); this.style['stroke-width'] = 1;"></rect>

<rect id="greenlight" x="55" y="225" height="60" width="50" fill="green" 
onmouseover="this.style.stroke = 'green'; evt.target.setAttribute('opacity', '1.0'); this.style['stroke-width'] = 4;" 
onmouseout="this.style.stroke = 'green'; evt.target.setAttribute('opacity', '0.5'); this.style['stroke-width'] = 1;"></rect>

</svg>
```

I have tried multiple combinations of fill-opacities and the code provided was just from my most recent attempt.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0a5yr7js/)

Comment: what about setting the `opacity` property to 0.5 in the svg ? https://jsfiddle.net/0a5yr7js/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to set the initial opacity value to 0.5.

Try this:

```html
<svg width="500" height="800">
<line x1="100" y1="100" x2="400" y2="100" style="stroke: green; stroke-width:50" />
<line x1="400" y1="0" x2="400" y2="600" style="stroke: green; stroke-width:50" />
<rect x="300" y="600" height="100" width="200"></rect>

<rect id="stoplight" x="30" y="0" height="300" width="100" fill="black"></rect>

<rect id="redlight" x="55" y="25" height="60" width="50" fill="red"  opacity="0.5" onmouseover="this.style.stroke = 

'red'; evt.target.setAttribute('opacity', '1.0'); this.style['stroke-width'] = 4;"
       onmouseout="this.style.stroke = 'red'; evt.target.setAttribute('opacity', '0.5'); 

this.style['stroke-width'] = 1;"></rect>
    
<rect id="yellowlight" x="55" y="125" height="60" width="50" fill="yellow"  opacity="0.5"

onmouseover="this.style.stroke = 'yellow';  evt.target.setAttribute('opacity', '1.0'); 

this.style['stroke-width'] = 4;"
       onmouseout="this.style.stroke = 'yellow'; evt.target.setAttribute('opacity', 

'0.5');this.style['stroke-width'] = 1;"></rect>
    
<rect id="greenlight" x="55" y="225" height="60" width="50" fill="green" opacity="0.5"

onmouseover="this.style.stroke = 'green'; evt.target.setAttribute('opacity', '1.0'); 

this.style['stroke-width'] = 4;" 
       onmouseout="this.style.stroke = 'green'; evt.target.setAttribute('opacity', '0.5'); 

this.style['stroke-width'] = 1;"></rect>

</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you. It's been driving me crazy. I have been doing 'fill-opacity="0.5"' rather than 'opacity="0.5"' as initial